# emacs does not open a file from argument and syntax highlight does not work

Tags: emacs, ubuntu

In my latest ubuntu box,

1. When I type for example `emacs ~/.bashrc`, Emacs will start but not open `.bashrc`.  This is true for any file I pass in.  I've used Emacs for several years, and have never experienced this problem before.
2. I added `(global-font-lock-mode 1);;` to my .emacs file, and Emacs does recognize it, for example. `"(C++/; Abbrev)"`, but it won't do syntax highlighting.

If you can solve any of these problems, it will be very appreciated. The following is my machine's configuration:

> uname -a
> Linux 2.6.35-28-generic-pae #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 14:58:06 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
>
> ~/.emacs
> (global-font-lock-mode 1);;

Comment: Better asked on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What happens if you start emacs then use `C-x C-f` to open `~/.bashrc`? Might give you a useful error message.

Comment: Does the `*Messages*` buffer contain anything useful?

Comment: hi thanks a lot, it seems it is caused by the directory ~/.emacs.d, emacs actually complains upon startup :"~/.emacs.d already exists". So I removed ~/.emacs.d, and now everything works! (I can open files through command line argument and syntax highlighting also works now). @Tom, previously I can start emacs, and then use C-x C-f to open .bashrc, but cannot open by > emacs ~/.bashrc

Comment: Here on #WSL2, only `emacs -nw filename` works, `emacs filename` opens an X11 window without opening a file.

Answer (score 35):

I got the same problem.
It was due to the fact I first used emacs with sudo.
As a consequence the .emacs.d was created with super user right and I could not access it as a regular user.

By removing the .emacs.d created as root let emacs generate a new one with your user account.

Comment: or you can simply change owner `sudo chown -hR <groupname>:<username> .emacs.d/`

Comment: Yep, this fixed the problem. It'd be great if emacs showed some information about this error...

Comment: There *really* ought to be some kind of diagnostic about this.  This must happen a lot when emacs is used as a system administration tool.

Answer (score 4):

You can have both `~/.emacs` file and `~/.emacs.d/` directory, but Emacs will ignore `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file. Emacs only evaluates `~/.emacs.d/init.el` when there is no `~/.emacs`. (Thanks, [pyrocrasty](https://superuser.com/users/122411/pyrocrasty)).

See: [The Emacs Initialization File @ GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Comment: That's not true at all. I used a `~/.emacs` file for years and I certainly always had a `~/.emacs.d/` directory. There won't be any conflict unless you have a `~/.emacs` file and a `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file at the same time, and even then, Emacs will just ignore one (I believe it prioritizes `~/.emacs`).

Comment: If you correct an error, in the future please don't strike it out, but just *remove* it entirely. Thanks. I left the comment stay so you can actually tell its posted that you corrected your answer. (They may upvote you or undo a downvote.)

Answer (score -1):

`initial-buffer-choice` in `startup.el` allows initial file customization.

Comment: perhaps some context would be helpful. An example config?